# Best way to organize Players into Teams in MiniGames to also use make use of certain features available in org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team interface

Tags: java, bukkit

I recently had an idea for a minecraft-minigame plugin.

Here, I need to organize Players into Teams. A few years back, I would have just made a new class `Team`, with add, remove methods etc.. However, I also want to implement features like friendly-fire, being able to see invisible teammates, setting name-tag visibility and make use of the sidebar-scoreboard.
Those are all features available in the `org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team`interface [Spigot-API 1.15.2 Team Interface Javadoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Team.html).

Is it possible to create my own class `Team implements org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team`, where I could make use of the Interface and also add own methods and features?

I am concerned this wouldn't work, because you normally get a `org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team` by calling

```
myScoreboard.registerNewTeam("TEAM_NAME");
```

and you cannot add an existing `org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team`-object to a scoreboard.
This plugin should work in different versions of spigot (like 1.8+), and I don't know how each version handles Scoreboard Teams beside the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not implement the team interface to use the functions, but you could make a wrapper class that can acces the function.

An example wrapper class:

```
class CustomTeam {
    private Team team;

    public CustomTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public customFunc() {
        //you can use the "team" here to do stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, why didn't I think of that? Sometimes I just feel stupid xD